# Will the object change its hidden class if we create new prototype properties?

Tags: javascript, prototype, v8, internals

In V8, an object changes its [hidden class](https://developers.google.com/v8/design) when a new property is added.

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x; // This will create new hidden class
  this.y = y; // This too
}
```

My question is simple, will this create a new hidden class?

```
Point.prototype.z = null;
```

I ask this question because in a coding style guideline I have read, they said we should declare class properties by creating a prototype instead of assigning them in the constructor. This will also help us to easily document them with JSDoc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of V8, but declaring properties on the prototype uses less memory, in case that's a relevant consideration. But be careful to avoid unintentionally shared object properties (see http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1566-using-super-constructors-is-critical-in-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript.htm).

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect. The code which supposedly won't run executes just fine in jsBin (http://jsbin.com/hawuhoga/1/edit?js,console). Its assertion that prototypes are copied upon object construction is totally incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is *yes*: a new hidden class will be created. However it's important to understand that it will be the **prototype** object itself that will change its hidden class, not an object created by the Point constructor.

Any object has a hidden class attached to it. Lets look at the code

```js
var o = new Point();
o.z = 0;  // (1)
Point.prototype.zz = 0;  // (2)
```

At any given moment any object has a hidden class, that means `o`, `o.__proto__`, `o.__proto__.__proto__` have a distinctive hidden class associated with them.

When you add a new property to the object, it's only hidden class of that object that changes. If you change hidden class of the prototype, the hidden classes of objects that share that prototype **do not** change. There is no need for such a change because we don't expect hidden class of an object `X` to fully describe the layout of any object in its whole prototype chain, its hidden class describes layout of `X` and `X` alone. Furthermore it's simply infeasible to implement such downwards propagation: that would require VM to maintain backward links between prototypes and all associated objects: to be able at any moment for an object `X` to enumerate all objects `Y` that have `Y.__proto__ === X`.

For the code above that means that statement `(1)` changes **only** the hidden class of `o` and statement `(2)` changes **only** the hidden class of `Point.prototype` (which is the same object as `o.__proto__`) but **not** of `o` itself.

Furthermore if you consider the code like this:

```js
Point.prototype.z = 0;  // Initial value
var o1 = new Point();
o1.z = 11;  // (3)
var o2 = new Point();
```

which is sometimes recommended then this is a performance antipattern precisely because hidden classes of `o1` / `o2` and `Point.prototype` are disconnected. Assignment at `(3)` would change the hidden class of `o1` even though `o1.__proto__` already has property `z`. Objects `o1` and `o2` will end up having different hidden classes which will cause all the code that uses both of them to go polymorphic and penalize the performance. Furthermore `o1` will end up using more space than in case if `z` was added right in the constructor because `z` would be stored in the out-of-object property storage.